# RSS feed not generating for custom post type after wordpress 3.8.1 update

Tags: wordpress, rss

Rss feeds seem to be generating for the category and home pages but not for the custom post type  page.I have used custom post type and not the default post.I am getting the feeds for custom post type in  wordpress 3.6 version but not for 3.8.1.It seems the version is a problem but i tried generating feeds for the default post using version 3.8.1 and it showed the posts.The problem seems to be with the version as well as the custom post type.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following function in your functions.php (replace the elements in the array with the     slug of your custom post type

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Add the management of custom type (Etudes et Standard) in the rss                    */
/*   source : http://www.seomix.fr/custom-post-type-wordpress-rss/                       */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    function myfeed_request($qv) {
        if (isset($qv['feed']) && !isset($qv['post_type']))
            $qv['post_type'] = array('etudes', 'standard');
        return $qv;
    }
    add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');
```